# Why flex item with flex-basis: auto doesn't get all available space if its content's width is 100%?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.first>input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="first"><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="second"><button>Button</button></div>
 </div>
```

In this sample I'm doing something with the `input`'s styles that will shrink its width as the `.parent`'s width becomes smaller itself. However, it puzzles me why, as long as the `.parent`'s width is more than enough, the `.first>input` brotherhood don't take up all the available space? There are no `max-width` set on them, so why should they freeze up in a flex container? What's the rules here?

Comment: `.parent` has no `width` defined, so flex child elements will only take what they need like any regular element. They will only take 100% of the parent width which is default `auto`.

Comment: @RenevanderLende probably I am getting you wrong but in this case, conversely, the children do *not* take up all 100% width of the parent, which is distinguishible behavior from the block formatting context and confuses me (if `display: block;` is set on `.parent`, the `.first` would stretch across the whole line)

Comment: I see what's going on. You embedded the `<input>` and `<button>` in `<div>`s. So the `<div>`s are the Flexbox children, not the `<tags>` inside them. Flex child properties only work one level deep.

Comment: @RenevanderLende when `flex-basis: auto` is set it means the width of a flex item depends on it content. The question is what is this content's width here, when we have an `input` with `display: block;` and `width: 100%;`. It seems a user agent has some width value for this case but I don't know is this value arbitrary or not.

Answer (score 1):

> `flex-basis: auto` looks up the main size of the element and defines the size. For example, on a horizontal flex container, `auto` will look for width and height if the container axis is vertical. If no size is specified, `auto` will fall back to content.

~ [Flex Basis Property in Flexbox](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/flex-basis-property-in-flexbox/)

So in your case, no size was specified on the flex container. Set the `flex-basis` on the parent of the element you are trying to grow. In your case, it would be `.first`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first>input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.first {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="second"><button>Button</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in fact I'm aware of how to make a flex item to take up the available space. I would like to figure out the rules cause the described behavior.

Comment: @IlyaLoskutov `input`'s are block-level. Meaning if they are nested in a `div` and you define a width on the block-level element, it won't really matter unless the width of the `parent` is defined. You will have to define `width: 100%;` on `first`.

Comment: You asked: **"Why flex item with flex-basis: auto doesn't get all available space if its content width is 100%?"** The answer to that question is clearly stated in the quote from my solution if you read it. It is also reiterated by @RenevanderLende in the comments.

Comment: *If no size is specified, auto will fall back to content* (from your citation) - keeping it in mind I would have no question as long as the child of the `.first` is text (`.first` would do its best to accommodate all the text without line wrapping) or an empty div (`.first`'s width would be zero). But in this specific case (the child is `input` although with `display: block;`) the picture in some way different: we have this `input`'s width set to some (arbitrary or not - it's the very my question) value.